# Extracting an integer command-line argument and printing a sum of numbers up to that limit

Tags: haskell

The below code works fine but I have the feeling that there must be something more idiomatic way to do this within the `do`-notation without having to resort to the two `liftM`s?

```
main = do
  n <- (liftM read (liftM head getArgs)) :: IO Int
  putStrLN . show $ sum [1..n]
```

If I do:

> ```
> main = do
>   args <- getArgs
>   arg1 <- head args
>   n <- read arg1 :: IO Int
>   putStrLn . show $ sum [1..n]
> ```

I get:

```
Expected type: String
  Actual type: Char
In the first Argument of 'read', namely 'arg1'
```

which I do not understand. `<- getArgs` returns IO [String], so `<- head args` should return `IO String`, but it seems to return `IO Char`?! (as per error message).

So my two questions are:

1. what is the most idiomatic way do do this
2. what's wrong in the second version?

Comment: `main = do [n] <- getArgs; print $ sum [1..read n]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have the Feeling that there must be something more idiomatic way to do this within the do-notation withouth having to resort to the two liftMs?

Yes, a single one. `liftM` is `fmap` nowadays. It stems from a time when `Functor` wasn't a superclass for `Monad`. The `Functor` laws state that

```
fmap f . fmap g = fmap (f . g)
```

Therefore, we can simplify

```
liftM read (liftM head getArgs)
```

to

```
fmap (read . head) getArgs
```

We end up with

```
main = do
  n <- fmap (read . head) getArgs :: IO Int
  putStrLN . show $ sum [1..n]
```

Also, `putStrLn . show` is `print`. If we introduce a small helper function, the code gets more readable:

```
readFirstElement :: Read a => [String] -> a 
readFirstElement = read . head

sumNaturalUpTo :: Int -> Int
sumNaturalUpTo n = sum [1..n]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  n <- readFirstElement <$> getArgs
  print $ sumNaturalUpTo n
```

Note that `sum [1..n]` is `` n * (n + 1) `div` 2 ``, though, so we can optimize `sumNaturalUpTo` to

```
sumNaturalUpTo n = n * (n + 1) `div` 2
```

Alternatively, we can write

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   args <- getArgs
   print $ sumNaturalUpTo $ readFirstElement args
```

Which might be the easiest one to read.

> what's wrong in the second version?

`args` is not a `IO …` value.

Comment: So `(<$>) = fmap`?

Comment: @ASz Right.  I'm sure I had that in a draft., sorry.

Answer (score 4):

This is the code you're looking for:

```
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  let arg1 = head args
  let n = (read arg1) :: Int
  putStrLn . show $ sum [1..n]
```

Think of the `<-` operator as "extract". It "pulls" a value out of a monad.

But once you've pulled `args` out of the `IO` monad, you've now got a pure list of strings. It's not in the `IO` monad, so you can't extract from it. `let` instead just does a pure binding like you're used to in non-monadic code, which is what you need here.